# MySQL Select and then echo out results

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
$sql_2 = 'SELECT id, firstname, lastname, birthday, location, occupation, telephone, email, picture FROM pinkmoon_pending ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1';
$result_2 = mysql_query($sql_2);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_2)
{
   $firstname = row['firstname'];
   $lastname  = row['lastname'];
   $birthday  = row['birthday'];
   $location  = row['location'];
   $occupation= row['occupation'];
   $telephone = row['telephone'];
   $email     = row['email'];
   $picture   = row['picture'];
}
mysql_free_result($result_2);
```

This is what I've tried to show me rows after SELECT-ing them with PHP.

This doesn't seem to work - Can anyone help me out please? :)

Comment: You don't need to do a loop when you're limiting the result to max. 1 row, `if` would be enough. And use `mysql_fetch_assoc` when using associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `mysql_fetch_row` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`. The former only indexes the results by number, not by field name.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_2))
```

You missed a `)`

Comment: While you are correct, it still won't work. see Kaivosukeltaja's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_2)
- {
-    $firstname = row['firstname'];
-    $lastname  = row['lastname'];
-    $birthday  = row['birthday'];
-    $location  = row['location'];
-    $occupation= row['occupation'];
-    $telephone = row['telephone'];
-    $email     = row['email'];
-    $picture   = row['picture'];
- }

+ while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_2)) {
+     foreach ($row as $item) {
+         echo $item;
+     }
+ }
```